# Reuse HttpMessageHandler with multiple Grpc clients

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpclient, grpc-c#

I have multiple Grpc clients and each need to pack a client certificate. I am using Grpc.Net.ClientFactory to register all my clients.

Not understanding how HttpMessageHandler should be reused, I am concerned about creating a new HttpMessageHandler for each Grpc client being registered as Microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests#httpclient-lifetimes) indicates that

> each handler typically manages its own underlying HTTP connections; creating more handlers than necessary can result in connection delays

```
// register serviceAClient
builder.Services.AddGrpcClient<ServiceA.ServiceAClient>(o => o.Address = new Uri(serviceUrl))
    .ConfigureChannel(o => o.HttpHandler = GetHttpHandler(certThumbprint));
        
// register serviceBClient
builder.Services.AddGrpcClient<ServiceB.ServiceBClient>(o => o.Address = new Uri(serviceUrl))
    .ConfigureChannel(o => o.HttpHandler = GetHttpHandler(certThumbprint));

// creates a new HttpMessageHandler 
private static HttpMessageHandler GetHttpHandler(string certThumbprint)
{
    var httpHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler()
    {
        PooledConnectionIdleTimeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan,
        KeepAlivePingDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60),
        KeepAlivePingTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
        EnableMultipleHttp2Connections = true,
        SslOptions = new SslClientAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientCertificates = LoadClientCertificates(certThumbprint)
        };
    
    return httpHandler;
}
```

What is the better way to deal with HttpMessageHandler in multiple Grpc clients scenario - should each client be registered with a single HttpMessageHandler? Or each client should have its own HttpMessageHandler like in the example above? What are the trade-offs here?

Comment: Why don't you just keep a single handler in a `static` field? They are completely thread-safe anyway.

Comment: That's what I am torn between whether to use a single handler across multiple clients or let each client has its own handler. Besides being thread-safe, any other insights on consequences of sharing a handler across multiple clients? Would it impact performance because of any connection limitations per handler?

Comment: No cam't think of any issues. Connection limits are handled automatically by opening new connections. The only issue is if you need different handling per client.

Answer (score 1):

According to this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/performance?view=aspnetcore-8.0#reuse-grpc-channels.

> A gRPC channel should be reused when making gRPC calls. Reusing a channel allows calls to be multiplexed through an existing HTTP/2 connection.
> Multiple gRPC clients can be created from a channel, including different types of clients.

It is better to reuse same channel for multiple clients.

```
var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(new Uri(serviceUrl), new GrpcChannelOptions
{
    HttpHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler
    {
        SslOptions = new SslClientAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientCertificates = LoadClientCertificates(certThumbprint)
        },
        ...   
    }
});
builder.Services.AddGrpcClient<ServiceA.ServiceAClient>(o => new ServiceA.ServiceAClient(channel));
builder.Services.AddGrpcClient<ServiceB.ServiceBClient>(o => new ServiceB.ServiceBClient(channel));
```

Comment: I'd rather let Grpc.Net.ClientFactory take care of the channel creation. I am only looking for setting certain properties on the HttpMessageHandler, that's it. The problem is I am not sure whether to create a new HttpMessageHandler for each typed Grpc client, or to reuse one.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up "modifying" the HttpMessageHandler instead of adding/replacing one.

This approach feels better as its not invasive in how Grpc.Net.ClientFactory is taking care of the grpcChannel and the underlying http connections and that default chain of HttpMessageHandler is preserved.

This approach however assumes that the final http handler is always the SocketsHttpHandler.

```
services.AddGrpcClient<ServiceA.ServiceAClient>(o => o.Address = new Uri(serviceUrl))
    .ConfigureChannel(o => o.HttpHandler.ConfigureHttpHandler(clientCertificateThumbprint));

services.AddGrpcClient<ServiceB.ServiceBClient>(o => o.Address = new Uri(serviceUrl))
    .ConfigureChannel(o => o.HttpHandler.ConfigureHttpHandler(clientCertificateThumbprint));
    
private static void ConfigureHttpHandler(this HttpMessageHandler? handler, string certificateThumbprint)
{
    // find the SocketsHttpHandler and configure it
    while (handler != null)
    {
        if (handler is DelegatingHandler delegatingHandler)
        {
            handler = delegatingHandler.InnerHandler;
        }
        else if (handler is SocketsHttpHandler socketsHttpHandler)
        {
            socketsHttpHandler.PooledConnectionIdleTimeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;
            socketsHttpHandler.KeepAlivePingDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
            socketsHttpHandler.KeepAlivePingTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
            socketsHttpHandler.EnableMultipleHttp2Connections = true;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(certificateThumbprint))
            {
                socketsHttpHandler.SslOptions = new SslClientAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientCertificates = LoadClientCertificates(certificateThumbprint)
                };
            }

            break;
        }
        else
        {
            log($"Unexpected HttpMessageHandler of type {handler.GetType()}.");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```